# Full Calendar issue on implementing

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having an issue with implementing FullCalendar...
And i think, i did all the things said on "Basic Usage" topic at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/ 
Why that piece of code doesn't appear my callendar on my .html ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        Callendar Test
    </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar.css' />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here


            })

        });  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any solution ?

P.S.: I downloaded the Jquery file (version 1.x) and put on the same file as my HTML page.

Errors:

```
Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:107
18:50:38.058 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for              'filter'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:133
18:50:38.058 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:213
18:50:38.058 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:214
18:50:38.058 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:215
18:50:38.058 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:255
18:50:38.058 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:414
18:50:38.059 Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. fullcalendar.css:532
18:50:38.059 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:575
18:50:38.059 Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. fullcalendar.css:580
18:50:38.092 ReferenceError: moment is not defined fullcalendar.js:12
18:50:38.094 The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. FullCalendar.html
18:50:38.116 TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

Here it is my directory :

[image]

Comment: Open your browser console see What error you are getting

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here...? You renamed the jQuery file to `jquery.js`, and your `calendar.js` as well as your `html page` are all on the same local area? You probably just have a typo in your filenames, much like in your `title` **Callendar**. It's `fullcalendar.js`.

Comment: i didn't renamed my callendar

Comment: fullcalendar is not live in your html directory it will be somewhere inside js folder?

Comment: it's on the same level as my .html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18:50:38.092 ReferenceError: moment is not defined fullcalendar.js:12

18:50:38.116 TypeError: **$(...).fullCalendar** is not a function.

In your `calendar.js`, it would appear that you don't have a function that has an `event handler` that can target a `specific id` with jQuery.

## Edit:

Not sure what you're doing wrong, but I have everything working just fine, just as you have it set up.

- http://www.sinsysonline.com/calendar/index2.html

As you can see, this is ALL of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my **entire** directory:

[image]

**Here is a full repository of the files that are working just fine.**

http://www.sinsysonline.com/calendar/test/full_package.zip

Comment: Working fine on my site with your code. Feel free to view source.

Comment: i saw your code, and you have some more link is that normal ?

Comment: You know what I think? Try linking your jQuery how I did with a `CDN`. You may have downloaded some weird copy. Also, set your `DOCTYPE` as I have, using HTML 5. You have another error where your doctype was undeclared.

Comment: I downloaded on jquery webpage, i will do the CDN !

Comment: Just as a test. Just try linking to the CDN and let me know what happens. Also, change your `doctype` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Even with your code, i couldn't make it !
It's saying some errors !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46118/discussion-between-nicholas-hazel-and-damiii)

Comment: My file "fullCalendar.js" was broken ! I tested your code and used that file and it wasn't working ! Maybe it's due to that file

Comment: That seems to prove the error I initially posted. `18:50:38.092 ReferenceError: moment is not defined fullcalendar.js:12`

Comment: One think that i do in my programs when i used calendar then without doing anythink i add moment.js file because if u r apply date formats then they wouldn't work without this library. . .

Answer (score 27):

Just in case someone else finds this thread through Google and is having this same problem:
If you are using the **hosted** libraries for FullCalendar, you must include moment.js (not available on the hosted libraries, it seems, so you have to download it) ***before*** you include the fullcalendar.js file. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

FullCalendar apparently has some references to the Moment object even before it's instantiated.

Hope that helps someone out.

Comment: Ok ! :) Thanks ! Didn't remember about that ( i must say) :)

Answer (score 6):

You must check the order of the js.

```
moment.min.js
fullcalendar.js
lang-all.js
```

Comment: Thank you Jaun that help my problem , as i was getting a moment not defined

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include MomentJS first as fullcalendar.js requires this.

This was my mistake and I received the same error.

```
<script src="/includes/js/fullcalendar-2.0.1/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/includes/js/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `js` file is not present at the location where you are trying to access it from.

Please update the href attribute of the source element to the source location where your JS file is present!

For solution, please open the Console and look for the error. It would be 404! Which means file not found.

For Chrome press CTRL + SHIFT + J

Comment: you mean my calendar ?

Comment: Yes, your calender source is not being loaded into the DOM! Try to recheck whether the file is loaded or not ..

Comment: Both are present on the same file !
FullCalendar -> fullcalendar.css
FullCalendar -> FullCalendar.html
FullCalendar -> jquery.js