# Why is moment undefined in my fullcalendar-scheduler implementation in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, momentjs

There are no issues when I only implement `fullcalendar`, but I get a moment error when I try to implement `fullcalendar-scheduler`.

Here is my code:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('moment');
require('fullcalendar');
require('fullcalendar-scheduler');
```

And my react class:

```
var Calendar = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function () {

        var resources = this.props.venues;

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            events: [

            ],
            resources: resources
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id='calendar'></div>
        );
    }
});
```

Simply commenting out the `require('fullcalendar-scheduler')` line allows my code to run, and the calendar pops up. But including it gives me this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

I saw in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367623/full-calendar-issue-on-implementing) that I should include moment before fullcalendar, which I am doing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your build system? Browserify or Webpack or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReactJS does not support global variables, which is what this calendar seems to need. You may use Flux or Redux, which has the ability to add these things.

The other option is to import the moment.js into the head of the document, which will attach a global variable.

Comment: Oops forgot to mention that I had it like this initially. It didn't work.

Comment: See new explanation.

Comment: I don't think React cares one way or another, but your build system will.

Comment: React will use a global, but when you require it, it creates it within a different scope. See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: I ended up importing moment.js into the head of my document. I really wanted to avoid that but what can you do!